# Laravel 7: Generate named view-routes from blade files in directory

Tags: php, laravel, directory, routes

Is there a nice way, to solve this issue: I have a folder `ressources/views/project/content` with several blade teplates, let's say:

```
home.blade.php
how-to.blade.php
info.blade.php
best-way-to-score.blade.php
...
```

Right now, I define one view route per file:

```
Route::view('/home', 'project.content.home')->name('home');
Route::view('/how-to', 'project.content.how-to')->name('how-to');
...
```

How can I create these routes on thy fly? I could solve it with a loop through all files in this directory, but maybe there is a more elegant way/function in laravel I don't know yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you you need is a generic get route like this:

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@show');
```

and then you need a PageController with a function to return the requested page:

```
public function show($page)
{
    return view('project.content.'.$page);
}
```

Just have in mind that this kind of route will "catch" every get request so put it at the end of the web.php file

Comment: and you can also give your route a name and then pass the page name as parameter : `{{ 
route('your_route_name','the_page_name') }}`